Can't deploy a MAUI application on Windows because of missing splash screen
I have my .NET 8 MAUI application that was working fine for all operating systems. From today, the Windows application raises an error

DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] AppxManifest.xml(40,27): error 0x80070002: Cannot install or update package 28305EnricoRossini.5358301F8C243_stw6y81gbfp6c because the splash screen image [splashSplashScreen.png] cannot be located. Verify that the package contains an image that can be used as a splash screen for the application, and that the package manifest points to the correct location in the package where this splash screen image can be found.

I haven't updated any NuGet packages. The list of packages is in the following screenshot:

I saw other posts like this one but it is quite old - 2022 & 2023 - and based on .NET 7. I can't find anything related to .NET 8.
Then, I tried to clean the application, rebuild and deploy. If the application starts, it can't find the debugger.

The application is working fine on Android.

Check the Package.appxmanifest on the Windows platform to ensure the SplashScreen location is correct set.
